# Updating SQL table using mysql python module

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I am attempting to update a single value in a single cell in a SQL table using the mysql connector for python. Using the following code, I get no error messages, but nor does the table actually update. The value of the cell that I am attempting to update is sometimes empty, sometimes NULL, and sometimes contains a string. Here is my code:

```
query = ("UPDATE data_set SET %s = '%s' WHERE id = %s") % (column_to_change, change_to_value, row_id)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Thanks for the replies so far. I do not think there is any functional issue with the surrounding code (outside of the vulnerability to SQL injection, which I have fixed, here and elsewhere), as I have been effective executing similar code with different queries. Here is my code now:

```
column_to_change = "column2"
change_to_value = "james"
id = "1234"


cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='password',
                          host='db.website.com',
                          database='database')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = ("UPDATE data_set SET %s = %s WHERE policy_key = %s")

cursor.execute(query, (column_to_change, change_to_value, id))

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

If it's relevant, it turns out the cells I'm trying to insert into are formatted as VARCHAR(45). When I run a SELECT query on a cell, it returns a name formatted like: (u'James',)

If I set change_to_value = "(u'James',)", I receive the following error message:

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntac; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''column1' = '(u\'James\',)' WHERE id = '1234'' at line 1

Comment: You should user parameterized queries and not create them using string formatting! Also, did you call `commit()`?

Comment: No, I did not call commit(), but I just added it in and I receive the same error that I explained in my edit.

Comment: While you _should_ use parameters for query parameters, _don't_ use them for identifiers (tablenames, colum names), those use different quote characters (backticks), so you'll get an sql syntax error.

Comment: @mata Thanks for the advice - so what exactly should I do? I just ran through every configuration I could think of - sometimes I get an error, and sometimes just nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are following all the steps:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("SERVER=my.server;DATABASE=my_database;UID=my_user;PWD=my_password;",ansi=True)

cursor = conn.cursor()

query = ("UPDATE data_set SET %s = '%s' WHERE id = %s") % (column_to_change, change_to_value, row_id)

cursor.execute(query)
```

And also verify the SQL query that your passing to `.execute()` is same as that you want to run on your database

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Python, perhaps it is an issue with your string interpolation. Otherwise, you may not be connecting your cursor and executing the query successfully. I am assuming you are executing your query elsewhere in your code, but in the instance you are not, this should work:

```
cursor.execute ("""
   UPDATE data_set
   SET %s=%s
   WHERE id=%s
""", (column_to_change, change_to_value, row_id))
```

Alternatively, you could store this query in a variable as you have done, assign the respective variables and execute afterward like so:

```
query = (“UPDATE data_set SET %s=%s WHERE id=%s”)

column_to_change = [YOUR ASSIGNMENT HERE]
change_to_value = [YOUR ASSIGNMENT HERE--if this is a string, it should be formatted as such here]
row_id = [YOUR  ASSIGNMENT HERE]

cursor.execute(query, (column_to_change, change_to_value, row_id))
```

Basic string interpolation is prone to SQL injection and should be avoided.

For more reference, see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html)

Comment: That won't work for the column name, column names use backticks as quote character, not single quotes.